# Googlemock! Error with my test. on call will by default return invoke

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock, arduino-esp8266

I'm writing a test with google test and google mock. I just refactored the code to make it testable. I'm passing in the Client object from main to this code. This way, the client object can be a real one when the main is running and a fake one when the tests are running. I'm trying to test how the Connection class uses the client object. I'm getting an error. Thanks in advance!

https://github.com/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/blob/doesnt_work/test/myConcreteConnectionTest.cpp

contents of myConcreteConnectionTest.cpp at

40e2a3063be74cc42703dfa1fc09ec37c198d530

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "myClient.hpp"
#include "myConcreteConnection.hpp"

using ::testing::A;
using ::testing::AtLeast;
using ::testing::Invoke;
using ::testing::InvokeWithoutArgs;
using ::testing::Matcher;
using ::testing::Return;
using ::testing::StrEq;
using ::testing::_;

class MockMyClient: public MyClient {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(connect, int(uint16_t port, const char *host));
    MOCK_METHOD1(print, size_t(const char[]));
    MOCK_METHOD0(connected, uint8_t());
    MOCK_METHOD0(read, int());
    MOCK_METHOD0(stop, void());
};

TEST(downloadData, basic) {
    int port = 80;
    const char *host = "api.coindesk.com";
    const char *path = "v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
    MockMyClient client; // connection happens through client
    MyConcreteConnection connection(&client, host, path); // connection prints text to client and reads from client
    std::string str = makeGetRequest(host, path); // the text that connection will print to client
    std::string json = "one two three {four five six}";
    EXPECT_CALL(client, print(Matcher<const char*>(StrEq(str.c_str())))).Times(1); // the client's print should be called with str
    ON_CALL(client, read()).WillByDefault(Return(InvokeWithoutArgs([&json]()->int { // when the connection calls the clients read, it should
        static auto it = json.begin();
        return (int)(*(it++)); // return the text in json
    })));
    std::string data = connection.read();
}

TEST(sanity, one) {
    ASSERT_EQ(1,1);
}
```

contents of myClient.hpp

```
#ifndef PROJECT_WIFICLIENTADAPTER_HPP
#define PROJECT_WIFICLIENTADAPTER_HPP

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

class MyClient {
public:
    virtual int connect(uint16_t port, const char *host) =0;
    virtual size_t print(const char[]) =0;
    virtual uint8_t connected() =0;
    virtual int read() =0;
    virtual void stop() =0;
};

#endif //PROJECT_WIFICLIENTADAPTER_HPP
```

contents of myConcreteConnection.hpp

```
#ifndef MYCONNECTION_HPP
#define MYCONNECTION_HPP

#include <string>
             #include "myConnection.hpp"
             #include "myClient.hpp"
             #include "makeGetRequest.hpp"
             #include "globals.hpp"

class MyConcreteConnection : MyConnection {
public:
    MyConcreteConnection(MyConcreteConnection& connection) : client(connection.client), port(connection.port), host(connection.host), path(connection.path) {};
    MyConcreteConnection(MyClient* c, const char *h, const char *p) : client(c), host(h), path(p) {
        client->print(makeGetRequest(host.c_str(), path.c_str()).c_str());
    };
    ~MyConcreteConnection() {
        client->stop();
    };
    size_t print(const char *cs) override { return client->print(cs); };
    std::string read() override {
        std::string data;
        for(int read = 0; (read = client->read()) > -1; data.push_back(static_cast<char>(read)));
        auto i = data.find('{');
        if (i == data.npos) {
            i = 0;
        }
        return data.substr(i);
    };
private:
    MyClient *client;
    uint16_t port;
    std::string host;
    std::string path;
};

#endif //MYCONNECTION_HPP
```

the error message

```
/home/richie/Downloads/JetBrains/clion-2017.1.2/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/cmake-build-debug --target hhTest -- -j 4
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/cmake-build-debug
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
Scanning dependencies of target gmock
[  8%] Building CXX object test/googletest/googlemock/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object test/googletest/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock.dir/__/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object test/googletest/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock.dir/src/gmock-all.cc.o
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libgmock.a
[ 41%] Linking CXX static library libgtest.a
/usr/bin/ar qc libgtest.a  CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
/usr/bin/ar qc libgmock.a  CMakeFiles/gmock.dir/__/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc.o CMakeFiles/gmock.dir/src/gmock-all.cc.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libgtest.a
/usr/bin/ranlib libgmock.a
[ 41%] Built target gmock
[ 41%] Built target gtest
Scanning dependencies of target gtest_main
[ 50%] Building CXX object test/googletest/googlemock/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o
[ 58%] Linking CXX static library libgtest_main.a
/usr/bin/ar qc libgtest_main.a  CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libgtest_main.a
[ 58%] Built target gtest_main
Scanning dependencies of target hhTest
[ 66%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/makeGetRequestTest.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/myConcreteConnectionTest.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/displayTest.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/__/pio/src/makeGetRequest.cpp.o
In file included from /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:58:0,
                 from /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/myConcreteConnectionTest.cpp:2:
/home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h: In instantiation of ‘testing::internal::ReturnAction<R>::Impl<R_, F>::Impl(const testing::internal::linked_ptr<T>&) [with R_ = testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::InvokeWithoutArgsAction<downloadData_basic_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> > >; F = int(); R = testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::InvokeWithoutArgsAction<downloadData_basic_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> > >]’:
/home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:557:44:   required from ‘testing::internal::ReturnAction<R>::operator testing::Action<Func>() const [with F = int(); R = testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::InvokeWithoutArgsAction<downloadData_basic_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> > >]’
/home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/myConcreteConnectionTest.cpp:38:8:   required from here
/home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:577:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘ImplicitCast_(testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::InvokeWithoutArgsAction<downloadData_basic_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> > >&)’
           value_(ImplicitCast_<Result>(value_before_cast_)) {}
                                       ^
In file included from /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:40:0,
                 from /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:58,
                 from /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/myConcreteConnectionTest.cpp:1:
/home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1377:11: note: candidate: template<class To> To testing::internal::ImplicitCast_(To)
 inline To ImplicitCast_(To x) { return x; }
           ^
/home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1377:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:58:0,
                 from /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/myConcreteConnectionTest.cpp:2:
/home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/test/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:577:39: note:   cannot convert ‘((testing::internal::ReturnAction<testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::InvokeWithoutArgsAction<downloadData_basic_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> > > >::Impl<testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::InvokeWithoutArgsAction<downloadData_basic_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> > >, int()>*)this)->testing::internal::ReturnAction<testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::InvokeWithoutArgsAction<downloadData_basic_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> > > >::Impl<testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::InvokeWithoutArgsAction<downloadData_basic_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> > >, int()>::value_before_cast_’ (type ‘testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::InvokeWithoutArgsAction<downloadData_basic_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> > >’) to type ‘int’
           value_(ImplicitCast_<Result>(value_before_cast_)) {}
                                       ^
test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/build.make:137: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/myConcreteConnectionTest.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/myConcreteConnectionTest.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:456: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:468: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/hhTest.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:279: recipe for target 'hhTest' failed
make: *** [hhTest] Error 2
```

Comment: Please clean this up by removing "-j4" and redoing the build.  You have parallel errors confusing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't recognize that. I just ran it without the -j 4 and I got the same output. I put it in a file and ran diff just to make sure.

`/home/richie/Downloads/JetBrains/clion-2017.1.2/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/richie/Documents/rgkirch/Hacker-HUD/cmake-build-debug --target hhTest -- > error-single.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It builds after I remove `Return()`.
It now reads

```
ON_CALL(client, read()).WillByDefault(InvokeWithoutArgs([&json]()->int { // when the connection calls the clients read, it should
static auto it = json.begin();
return (int)(*(it++)); // return the text in json
}));
```

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/HEAD/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md